# How to make CSS3 animation works in IE7/8/9

Tags: css

I have a question regarding [css3 animation](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/webkit-keyframe-animation-syntax/). I know that it works well in all browsers except Internet Explorer(IE-7/8/9). How can I make it work in the older versions of IE as well?

Comment: you cant, use jquery or some other library

Comment: The link is broken, I think you mean this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful [cssSandpaper – a CSS3 JavaScript Library](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/).

Comment: Undergoing the whole article, finding it very useful, haven't reached what i was looking for, but i think will get it, as the proceedings are going on.